# Using an array of percentages to determine probability?

Tags: java, arrays, probability

After trying a challenge in java to make a 'casino' style game, I've arrived at the point where I have an array with 10 values, each being the percentage change they can win. These are assigned to the same position in the array as their 'ids' are, eg. `playerid[i]` goes with player with percentage `percentageChance[i]`

At this stage, I'm at a loss as to where I can go to actually determine the 'winner'. I thought about making a random number from 1-100, and whichever range it lands in means that person wins, but I've no idea how to implement that, or whether there's a cleaner/more efficient technique.

Comment: Do the individual percentages for the players add up to 100?

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you are on the right track! Assuming all of the probabilities add up to 100, I would take a random number between 1 and 100 and then see where that lands in the array.

```
Random r = new Random();
int rand = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  sum += percentChance[i];
  if(sum <= rand){
       //player i wins
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all chances sum 100, simply take a number btw 1 and 100:

```
Random r = new Random();
int winner = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
```

And then get the winner position of the array:

```
int count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    count += chances[i];

    // this will give i position
    if (count >= winner) break;
}

System.out.println("Winner is " + playerid[i]);
```

Imagine you get `winner = 34`, take the chances array and get corresponding position for it.

```
chances = [10, 5, 5, 30, 5, 5, 5, 5, 25, 5];
```

First iteration count will be 10, nothing happens, after, 15, 20...

```
i  count  
-  -----
0  10
1  15 
2  20
3  50  count > winner so i=4 is the winner!
```